# Trying to create vectors and chunked data using Azure cognitive search/ Azure AI search

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai, vertex-ai-search

I am trying to create a search solution using Azure AI Search/cognitive search. I need to ***chunk the data,*** so that the retrieved text is limited and more relevant. I also need to ***implement a Hybrid search*** over the data hence trying out the embedding creation as well.

I tried using ***splittext and AzureOpenaiEmbedding skillsets*** however they are not getting indexed. My intention is to use OCR ,Key phrase extraction etc and get them collated using merge skill and then do chunking and embeddings over it. Also I would like to add Incremental indexing [updating the indexes without redoing the whole indexing] as an additional feature.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. any help will be highly appreciated.

The following is what I tried:

```
def create_skillset(skillset_name, uri, headers):
    print("Trying out updated 2 set ------------------------->")
    skillset = {
    "description": "Skillset created from the portal. skillsetName: azureblob-skillsetn; contentField: merged_content; enrichmentGranularity: document; knowledgeStoreStorageAccount: ;",
    "skills": [
        {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.V3.EntityRecognitionSkill",
        "name": "#1",
        "context": "/document/merged_content",
        "categories": [
            "Product",
            "PhoneNumber",
            "Person",
            "Quantity",
            "Organization",
            "IPAddress",
            "URL",
            "Email",
            "Event",
            "Skill",
            "Location",
            "PersonType",
            "Address",
            "DateTime"
        ],
        "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
        "inputs": [
            {
            "name": "text",
            "source": "/document/merged_content"
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
            "name": "persons",
            "targetName": "people"
            },
            {
            "name": "organizations",
            "targetName": "organizations"
            },
            {
            "name": "locations",
            "targetName": "locations"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.KeyPhraseExtractionSkill",
        "name": "#2",
        "context": "/document/merged_content",
        "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
        "inputs": [
            {
            "name": "text",
            "source": "/document/merged_content"
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
            "name": "keyPhrases",
            "targetName": "keyphrases"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
          "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
          "textSplitMode": "pages",
          "maximumPageLength": 500,
          "pageOverlapLength": 50,
          "maximumPagesToTake": 1,
          "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
          "context": "/document",
          "inputs": [
            {
              "name": "text",
              "source": "/document/merged_text"
            }
          ],
          "outputs": [
            {
              "name": "textItems",
              "targetName": "pages"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.TranslationSkill",
        "name": "#3",
        "context": "/document/merged_content",
        "defaultToLanguageCode": "en",
        "suggestedFrom": "en",
        "inputs": [
            {
            "name": "text",
            "source": "/document/merged_content"
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
            "name": "translatedText",
            "targetName": "translated_text"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.MergeSkill",
        "name": "#4",
        "context": "/document",
        "insertPreTag": " ",
        "insertPostTag": " ",
        "inputs": [
            {
            "name": "text",
            "source": "/document/content"
            },
            {
            "name": "itemsToInsert",
            "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/text"
            },
            {
            "name": "offsets",
            "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/contentOffset"
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
            "name": "mergedText",
            "targetName": "merged_content"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill",
        "description": "Connects a deployed embedding model.",
        "resourceUri": "https://MYRESOURCE.openai.azure.com/",
        "deploymentId": "text-embedding-ada-002",
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "text",
            "source": "/document/merged_content"
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "embedding"
          }
          ]
         },
        {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Vision.OcrSkill",
        "name": "#5",
        "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
        "lineEnding": "Space",
        "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
        "inputs": [
            {
            "name": "image",
            "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
            "name": "text",
            "targetName": "text"
            },
            {
            "name": "layoutText",
            "targetName": "layoutText"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Vision.ImageAnalysisSkill",
        "name": "#6",
        "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
        "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
        "visualFeatures": [
            "tags",
            "description"
        ],
        "details": [],
        "inputs": [
            {
            "name": "image",
            "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
            "name": "tags",
            "targetName": "imageTags"
            },
            {
            "name": "description",
            "targetName": "imageCaption"
            }
        ]
        }
    ],
    "cognitiveServices": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CognitiveServicesByKey",
        "description": "",
        "key": ""
    }
    }
    resp = requests.put(uri, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(skillset), verify=False)
    logging.info(f"Message: {resp.status_code}\n"
                 f"Message: {resp.ok}\n")

def create_index(index_name, uri, headers):
    index = {
    "fields": [
        {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "key": True,
        "searchable": True,
        "filterable": True,
        "facetable": True,
        "sortable": True
        },
        {
        "name": "metadata_storage_name",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": True,
        "filterable": False,
        "facetable": False,
        "sortable": False
        },
        {
        "name": "imageCaption",
        "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
        "searchable": True,
        "filterable": False,
        "facetable": False,
        "sortable": False
        },
        {
        "name": "imageTags",
        "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
        "searchable": True,
        "filterable": False,
        "facetable": False,
        "sortable": False
        },
        {
        "name": "translated_text",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": True,
        "filterable": False,
        "facetable": False,
        "sortable": False
        },
        {
        "name": "keyphrases",
        "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
        "searchable": True,
        "filterable": False,
        "facetable": False,
        "sortable": False
        },
        {
        "name": "merged_content",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": True,
        "filterable": True,
        "facetable": True,
        "sortable": True
        },
        {
        "name": "pages",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": True,
        "filterable": True,
        "facetable": True,
        "sortable": True
        },

    ]
    }
    resp = requests.put(uri, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(index), verify=False)
    logging.info(f"Message: {resp.status_code}\n"
             f"Message: {resp.ok}\n")

def create_indexer(indexer_name, datasource_name, index_name, skillset_name, uri, headers):
    indexer = {
    "name": indexer_name,
    "dataSourceName" : datasource_name,
    "targetIndexName" : index_name,
    "skillsetName" : skillset_name,
    "fieldMappings" : [
        {
        "sourceFieldName" : "metadata_storage_path",
        "targetFieldName" : "id",
        "mappingFunction" : {"name": "base64Encode"}
        },
        {
        "sourceFieldName" : "metadata_storage_name",
        "targetFieldName" : "metadata_storage_name",
        }
    ],
    "outputFieldMappings" :
    [
        {
        "sourceFieldName" : "/document/merged_content",
        "targetFieldName" : "merged_content"
        },
        {
        "sourceFieldName" : "/document/pages",
        "targetFieldName" : "pages"
        },
        {
        "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/translated_text",
        "targetFieldName": "translated_text"
        },
        {
        "sourceFieldName" : "/document/merged_content/keyphrases",
        "targetFieldName" : "keyphrases"
        },
        {
        "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/imageTags/*/name",
        "targetFieldName": "imageTags"
        },
        {
        "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/imageCaption",
        "targetFieldName": "imageCaption"
        }
    ],
    "parameters":
    {
        "maxFailedItems": 4,
        "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 4,
        "configuration":
        {
        "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
        "parsingMode": "default",
        "firstLineContainsHeaders": True,
        "delimitedTextDelimiter": ",",
        "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages"
        }
    }
    }
    resp = requests.put(uri, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(indexer), verify=False)
    logging.info(f"Message: {resp.status_code}\n"
                 f"Message: {resp.ok}\n")
```

*** I am calling these functions like this ***

```
# Delete already exisitng datasource
    uri = f"https://{service_name}.search.windows.net/datasources/{datasource_name}?api-version={api_version}"
    resp = requests.delete(uri, headers=headers, verify=False)

    uri = f"https://{service_name}.search.windows.net/indexers/{indexer_name}?api-version={api_version}"
    # Delete already existing indexer
    resp = requests.delete(uri, headers=headers, verify=False)
    con_str="hjgjhgkj"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(con_str)


    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    uri = f"https://{service_name}.search.windows.net/datasources?api-version={api_version}"
    create_datasource(datasource_name, uri, headers,container_name)
    time.sleep(15)

    uri = f"https://{service_name}.search.windows.net/skillsets/{skillset_name}?api-version={api_version}"
    #Delete already existing skillset
    resp = requests.delete(uri, headers=headers, verify=False)
    create_skillset(skillset_name, uri, headers)

    uri = f"https://{service_name}.search.windows.net/indexes/{index_name}?api-version={api_version}"
    # Delete already existing index
    resp = requests.delete(uri, headers=headers, verify=False)
    create_index(index_name, uri, headers)
    uri = f"https://{service_name}.search.windows.net/indexers/{indexer_name}?api-version={api_version}"
    create_indexer(indexer_name, datasource_name, index_name, skillset_name, uri, headers)
    uri = f"https://{service_name}.search.windows.net/indexers/{indexer_name}/status?api-version={api_version}"
    resp = requests.get(uri, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

The error i get is as follows:

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestParameter","message":"The request is invalid. Details: skillset : One or more skills are invalid. Details: Unexpected properties found on Skill.","details":[{"code":"InvalidSkillset","message":"One or more skills are invalid. Details: Unexpected properties found on Skill. Parameters: skillset"}]}}
```

the spittext and openai embeddings are the two new skillsets that i added, rest of it are working, I followed the azure documentation while creating these skillsets. Please advice on where am I going wrong.

Comment: To actually help answer your question, can you share the specific symptom you are experiencing? Is your indexer failing with a certain error, or is the indexer succeeding and you just aren't seeing some or all of the content in your index? Its worth noting that you mention wanting chunking, but I don't see a SplitSkill or IndexProjections as part of your skillset definition.

Comment: Thanks @CareyHalton. I do not see any error, but only data source is getting created, no indexer,indexes or skillsets are getting created.

Comment: Oh, are you running the methods mentioned in the post at all? I just see 3 methods designed to create a skillset, index and indexer but I don't see the code where you are actually calling these methods. If you are calling the methods, are you getting an error response for any of them that could help us identify what is wrong?

Comment: @CareyHalton of course I am calling those functions, I have added the same and the error as well.

Comment: Gotcha. Can you confirm which API version you are using? The new AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill as well as the new parameters on the SplitSkill are only available on 2023-10-01-preview so that could be the issue. Also, I took the exact skillset in your post and tried to create it myself and I had to remove the "name" parameter from all of the existing skills in order for it to work so you could try that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, the following 2 parameters are not available, even though it is thus mentioned in azure documentation. take these out and that will fix the splittext skill issue:

```
"pageOverlapLength": 50,
```

"maximumPagesToTake": 1,

for AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill, it is available only on 2023-10-01-preview api. you just need to change the api parameter while creating the skillset, it should work.

Comment: Those two new properties on the SplitSkill are available on the 2023-10-01-preview API as well.